# How to change timestamp precision from ms to us or ns when timestamp_precision settings reported error in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I read the user guide and startup process of Apache IoTDB, and they both stated that timestamp_precision parameter can be used to set timestamp precision as "ms", "us" or "ns".

However, when I tried to switch the timestamp precision from "ms" to "us" and "ns", an error was reported:

```
ERROR o.a.i.d.s.DataNodeServerCommandLine:83 - Meet error when doing start checking org.apache.iotdb.commons.exception.ConfigurationException: Parameter timestamp_precision can not be us, please set to ms.
```

It seems that the timestamp precision cannot be set to us and ns as the guide stated, so where and how can I set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the current timestamp need to be changed to us and ns, the data directory in Apache IoTDB must be deleted and restarted in Version 1.0.1. The newest version (1.1.0) already fixed this problem. You can choose which version to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).